# SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces returns ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER when querying bluetooth devices

Tags: windows, winapi, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to get a HANDLE from a Bluetooth Low Energy device by using CreateFile(). 
Therefore I need to extract the device path of the device. 
I get an  ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER error when calling SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces. It seems that the second parameter (DeviceInfoData) has a problem. 
Any ideas what the problem could be?

**EDITED: Simplified code**

```
HDEVINFO hDevInfo;
DWORD i;

// Create a HDEVINFO with all present devices.
hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(&GUID_DEVCLASS_BLUETOOTH, 0, 0, DIGCF_PRESENT);

if (hDevInfo == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    // Insert error handling here.
    return;//1;
}
PSP_DEVINFO_DATA DeviceInfoData = new SP_DEVINFO_DATA;
DeviceInfoData->cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA);

for (i = 0; SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(hDevInfo, i, DeviceInfoData); i++)
{
    DeviceInfoData->cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA);

    char detailDataBuf[0x100];
    PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA detailData = (PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA)detailDataBuf;
    ULONG length;
    ULONG requiredLength = 0;
    bool bResult = FALSE;

    for(DWORD j = 0; j < 10; j++ )
    {
        SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA interfaceData;
        interfaceData.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA);
        bResult = SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(hDevInfo, DeviceInfoData, &GUID_DEVCLASS_BLUETOOTH, j, &interfaceData );
        if (!bResult) {
            int lastError = GetLastError(); // always returns ERROR 259
            continue;
        }
        // Get the size of the buffer required to receive the device info
        SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(hDevInfo, &interfaceData, NULL, 0, &requiredLength, NULL );
        if( requiredLength >= sizeof( detailDataBuf ) )
            break;

        // Get the name of the device
        detailData->cbSize = sizeof( SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA );
        length = requiredLength;
        bResult = SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(hDevInfo, &interfaceData, detailData, length, &requiredLength, NULL ) != 0;
        if( !bResult )
            break;
    }
}
```

**EDITED2:**
Passing in NULL for `DeviceInfoData`: This simple case always returns false

```
HDEVINFO hDevInfo = SetupDiGetClassDevs(&GUID_DEVCLASS_BLUETOOTH, 0, 0, DIGCF_PRESENT | DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE);

bool bResult = FALSE;

for(DWORD j = 0; j < 10; j++ )
{
    SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA interfaceData;
    interfaceData.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA);
    bResult = SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(hDevInfo, NULL, &GUID_DEVCLASS_BLUETOOTH, j, &interfaceData );
    if (!bResult) {
        int lastError = GetLastError(); // ERROR 259
        continue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation says:

> DeviceInfoData [in, optional]
>
> A pointer to an SP_DEVINFO_DATA structure that specifies a device information element in DeviceInfoSet.

In other words, it must point to an element of `deviceInfo`, which the pointer you are passing doesn't.  If you don't want to filter the results to the interfaces of a specific device in the device information set, pass `NULL`.

(Note that this is an input parameter, as indicated by the "in" tag.  The output is passed via the fifth parameter, `DeviceInterfaceData`.)

Comment: thanks, I edited the code to point to hDevInfo but I still get the same error. Shouldn't SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo fill the DeviceInfoData?

Comment: The new code has the same mistake, i.e., `DeviceInfoData` doesn't point to an element of the device information set.  Regarding your comment, no, the function will not fill in `DeviceInfoData`.  That's an input parameter, not an output parameter.

Comment: But it's an output parameter for `SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo` that is used as an input for `SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces`, right? I also tried to pass NULL for the deviceInfo but that didn't work either. Any other ideas what's going on here?

Comment: I added a simple example to the original post which fails

Comment: "But it's an output parameter for ..." yes, in the code you first posted the problem was that DeviceInfoData pointed to a device information structure from a different device information set.  In the updated code it pointed to memory you'd allocated yourself.  Neither is valid.  Now that you're passing in NULL you're getting error 259 (no more data) which means the code is working.

Comment: If you are getting error 259 when `j == 0`, that means there are no device interfaces matching the specified criteria.  If you are getting it for `j > 0` it indicates when you've seen all the matching interfaces.